# Fixed navigation bar on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'm trying to make my navigation bar fixed top only when users visit the site when on mobile devices. so far I've tried to do this by using a media quires. it works when I use Google chrome feature "inspect" to view how my site looks on mobile, however when I upload the site and access it from an actual mobile device the navbar is no longer fixed at the top.  [**link to the site**](http://www.spartansafety.co.uk/index123.html)

Update: The fixed navbar doesn't work at all in safari and is positioned in the wrong place in google chrome

```
<!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</nav>
CSS


 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .navbar {
         position: fixed;
         z-index: 1;
         width: 100%;
     }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .carousel {
         margin-top: 60px;
     }
 }

 .navbar {
     background-color: #2A2F35;
     padding: 0 !important;
 }

 .navbar-nav a {
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-style: normal;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 22px;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     color: #ffffff !important;
     padding: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
     margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use this as a reference

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on my phone and the navbar seems to be fixed no problem. Maybe adding this meta tag will help you
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: what browser did you view it in?

Comment: Google Chrome Latest version on Android 8.0